# Xquery with multiple element with distinct clause

Tags: xml, xquery

in my xml files

```
<a>
   <test id="bk1">
         <go>B</go>
         <from>A</from>
   <test/>
   <test id="bk2">
         <go>C</go>
         <from>D</from>
   <test/>
   <test id="bk2">
         <go>D</go>
         <from>E</from>
   <test/>
</a>
```

so i want to select the go and from value and create an element call $elements

expected output:

```
<city>A</city>
<city>B</city>
<city>C</city>
<city>D</city>
<city>E</city>
```

in my xquery query:

```
for $a in /a/test
for $elements in distinct-values($go) //How to add from into elements ?
return
      <city>
            {$elements}
      </city>
```

Answer (score 3):

`distinct-values($sequence)` only accepts single sequence variables. But joining sequences is very easy in XQuery, as they automatically get flattened (there are no nested sequences in XQuery):

```
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

gets

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

You can easily reproduce this by executing the first line as an XQuery.

---

Applied to `distinct-values` and your question, values, execute

```
distinct-values($a/test/(go, from))
```

(and wrap this in the loop you already have).

Answer (score 2):

```
for $a in distinct-values(/a/test/(go|from))
return <city>{ $a }</city>
```